# Bootstrap a href inside top-menu not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing a problem with a menu div in bootstrap.

I have a top menu with four links which are pointing at a corresponding sections of my site.The links are "hijacked" by a jquery script so they will scroll the page to that section.
What i want to to is place a link to point to extrernal link,but when i place the `<a href` tag it does nothing.

My code

```
            <ul class="unstyled inline pull-right top-menu">
             <li><a href="http://myblog.tumblr.com">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>        
              <li><a href="#newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>                
            </ul>
```

Any ideas how i will bypass the scrollTo function only for my external link but contain it inside my menu div?

scrollTo jquery

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2012 Ariel Flesler - aflesler(at)gmail(dot)com | http://flesler.blogspot.com
 * Dual licensed under MIT and GPL.
 * @author Ariel Flesler
 * @version 1.4.3
 */
;(function($){var h=$.scrollTo=function(a,b,c){$(window).scrollTo(a,b,c)};h.defaults={axis:'xy',duration:parseFloat($.fn.jquery)>=1.3?0:1,limit:true};h.window=function(a){return $(window)._scrollable()};$.fn._scrollable=function(){return this.map(function(){var a=this,isWin=!a.nodeName||$.inArray(a.nodeName.toLowerCase(),['iframe','#document','html','body'])!=-1;if(!isWin)return a;var b=(a.contentWindow||a).document||a.ownerDocument||a;return/webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)||b.compatMode=='BackCompat'?b.body:b.documentElement})};$.fn.scrollTo=function(e,f,g){if(typeof f=='object'){g=f;f=0}if(typeof g=='function')g={onAfter:g};if(e=='max')e=9e9;g=$.extend({},h.defaults,g);f=f||g.duration;g.queue=g.queue&&g.axis.length>1;if(g.queue)f/=2;g.offset=both(g.offset);g.over=both(g.over);return this._scrollable().each(function(){if(!e)return;var d=this,$elem=$(d),targ=e,toff,attr={},win=$elem.is('html,body');switch(typeof targ){case'number':case'string':if(/^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ)){targ=both(targ);break}targ=$(targ,this);if(!targ.length)return;case'object':if(targ.is||targ.style)toff=(targ=$(targ)).offset()}$.each(g.axis.split(''),function(i,a){var b=a=='x'?'Left':'Top',pos=b.toLowerCase(),key='scroll'+b,old=d[key],max=h.max(d,a);if(toff){attr[key]=toff[pos]+(win?0:old-$elem.offset()[pos]);if(g.margin){attr[key]-=parseInt(targ.css('margin'+b))||0;attr[key]-=parseInt(targ.css('border'+b+'Width'))||0}attr[key]+=g.offset[pos]||0;if(g.over[pos])attr[key]+=targ[a=='x'?'width':'height']()*g.over[pos]}else{var c=targ[pos];attr[key]=c.slice&&c.slice(-1)=='%'?parseFloat(c)/100*max:c}if(g.limit&&/^\d+$/.test(attr[key]))attr[key]=attr[key]<=0?0:Math.min(attr[key],max);if(!i&&g.queue){if(old!=attr[key])animate(g.onAfterFirst);delete attr[key]}});animate(g.onAfter);function animate(a){$elem.animate(attr,f,g.easing,a&&function(){a.call(this,e,g)})}}).end()};h.max=function(a,b){var c=b=='x'?'Width':'Height',scroll='scroll'+c;if(!$(a).is('html,body'))return a[scroll]-$(a)[c.toLowerCase()]();var d='client'+c,html=a.ownerDocument.documentElement,body=a.ownerDocument.body;return Math.max(html[scroll],body[scroll])-Math.min(html[d],body[d])};function both(a){return typeof a=='object'?a:{top:a,left:a}}})(jQuery);
```

**jquery.nav**

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

    // our plugin constructor
    var OnePageNav = function(elem, options){
        this.elem = elem;
        this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.options = options;
        this.metadata = this.$elem.data('plugin-options');
        this.$nav = this.$elem.find('a');
        this.$win = $(window);
        this.sections = {};
        this.didScroll = false;
        this.$doc = $(document);
        this.docHeight = this.$doc.height();
    };

    // the plugin prototype
    OnePageNav.prototype = {
        defaults: {
            currentClass: 'current',
            changeHash: false,
            easing: 'swing',
            filter: '',
            scrollSpeed: 750,
            scrollOffset: 0,
            scrollThreshold: 0.5,
            begin: false,
            end: false,
            scrollChange: false
        },

        init: function() {
            var self = this;

            // Introduce defaults that can be extended either
            // globally or using an object literal.
            self.config = $.extend({}, self.defaults, self.options, self.metadata);

            //Filter any links out of the nav
            if(self.config.filter !== '') {
                self.$nav = self.$nav.filter(self.config.filter);
            }

            //Handle clicks on the nav
            self.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.handleClick, self));

            //Get the section positions
            self.getPositions();

            //Handle scroll changes
            self.bindInterval();

            //Update the positions on resize too
            self.$win.on('resize.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.getPositions, self));

            return this;
        },

        adjustNav: function(self, $parent) {
            self.$elem.find('.' + self.config.currentClass).removeClass(self.config.currentClass);
            $parent.addClass(self.config.currentClass);
        },

        bindInterval: function() {
            var self = this;
            var docHeight;

            self.$win.on('scroll.onePageNav', function() {
                self.didScroll = true;
            });

            self.t = setInterval(function() {
                docHeight = self.$doc.height();

                //If it was scrolled
                if(self.didScroll) {
                    self.didScroll = false;
                    self.scrollChange();
                }

                //If the document height changes
                if(docHeight !== self.docHeight) {
                    self.docHeight = docHeight;
                    self.getPositions();
                }
            }, 250);
        },

        getHash: function($link) {
            return $link.attr('href').split('#')[1];
        },

        getPositions: function() {
            var self = this;
            var linkHref;
            var topPos;
            var $target;

            self.$nav.each(function() {
                linkHref = self.getHash($(this));
                $target = $('#' + linkHref);

                if($target.length) {
                    topPos = $target.offset().top;
                    self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos) - self.config.scrollOffset;
                }
            });
        },

        getSection: function(windowPos) {
            var returnValue = null;
            var windowHeight = Math.round(this.$win.height() * this.config.scrollThreshold);

            for(var section in this.sections) {
                if((this.sections[section] - windowHeight) < windowPos) {
                    returnValue = section;
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        },

        handleClick: function(e) {
            var self = this;
            var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
            var $parent = $link.parent();
            var newLoc = '#' + self.getHash($link);

            if(!$parent.hasClass(self.config.currentClass)) {
                //Start callback
                if(self.config.begin) {
                    self.config.begin();
                }

                //Change the highlighted nav item
                self.adjustNav(self, $parent);

                //Removing the auto-adjust on scroll
                self.unbindInterval();

                //Scroll to the correct position
                $.scrollTo(newLoc, self.config.scrollSpeed, {
                    axis: 'y',
                    easing: self.config.easing,
                    offset: {
                        top: -self.config.scrollOffset
                    },
                    onAfter: function() {
                        //Do we need to change the hash?
                        if(self.config.changeHash) {
                            window.location.hash = newLoc;
                        }

                        //Add the auto-adjust on scroll back in
                        self.bindInterval();

                        //End callback
                        if(self.config.end) {
                            self.config.end();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        },

        scrollChange: function() {
            var windowTop = this.$win.scrollTop();
            var position = this.getSection(windowTop);
            var $parent;

            //If the position is set
            if(position !== null) {
                $parent = this.$elem.find('a[href$="#' + position + '"]').parent();

                //If it's not already the current section
                if(!$parent.hasClass(this.config.currentClass)) {
                    //Change the highlighted nav item
                    this.adjustNav(this, $parent);

                    //If there is a scrollChange callback
                    if(this.config.scrollChange) {
                        this.config.scrollChange($parent);
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        unbindInterval: function() {
            clearInterval(this.t);
            this.$win.unbind('scroll.onePageNav');
        }
    };

    OnePageNav.defaults = OnePageNav.prototype.defaults;

    $.fn.onePageNav = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            new OnePageNav(this, options).init();
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window , document );
```

Comment: Can you show the jQuery code you use to initialize the scrollTo plugin?

Comment: Looks like you need to change the selector of the scrollspy function? So if it's `$('.unstyled li a[href="#contact"]');` try changing to the rel tag instead `$('#myTab a[rel="#profile"]');` and change the list links accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used the scrollTo plugin, but with bootstrap I am using the following to have animated scrolling. Since I am only targeting links that start with `#` all of my other links work as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash) { //If page loads with hash
        scrollToID(window.location.hash);
    }
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event){ //Only target links that start with #
       event.preventDefault();
       scrollToID($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});     

function scrollToID(ID){
    var navOffset = ($(window).width() > 979) ? 93 : 0; //adjust this if you have a fixed header with responsive design
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $(ID).offset().top - navOffset
    }, 'slow');
}
```